# Run db2 command in jar without jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I'm writing a simple JAR executable which will run db2 queries, enrich returned data and generate a csv file.
The intention is to run the jar right on the db2 server, logged as a db2 user,
hence I don't need to set up the JDBC connection, like so:

```
String url = "jdbc:db2://"+ hostName+ ":" + port + "/" + dbName;
Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbUser,dbPassword)
```

In short, is there a way to execute the following snippet of code without dbConnection()?

```
String readQuery="SELECT FNAME FROM STUDENTS";
PreparedStatement pstmt = dbConnection().prepareStatement(readQuery);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: No. You still need a database connection. Even on the database server itself. The hostname can be localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Here's the deal the reason I'm approaching this problem in this fashion is because, even though I have these db2 libraries in the build path db2jcc_license_cur.jar, db2jcc4.jar db2java.zip defined, upon running my script I get prompted with: No suitable driver found for jdbc.db2....

Comment: The "No suitable driver" reults from using either incorrect classname or badly formatted connection string. Google swg21432559.